# How to Concatenate Two Columns in Ebean Like Clause

Tags: sql, ebean

I am attempting to find a user by his/her full name given some query string. Within my table, I have columns for "First_Name" and "Last_Name", but no column for "Full_Name".

Using Avaje Ebean, I would like to query with a `like` clause that concatenates "First_Name" and "Last_Name" and then compares it with `n%` (the name in the query). In SQL, the query would like like:

```
SELECT * FROM users
WHERE
concat(users.First_Name , ' ' , users.Last_Name) LIKE 'n%'
OR  users.First_Name LIKE 'n%' OR  users.First_Name LIKE '%n'
OR  users.Last_Name LIKE 'n%'  OR users.Last_Name LIKE '%n'
```

Is this possible to do with Ebean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible by [`RawSql`](http://www.avaje.org/ebean/introquery_rawsql.html)

I allows you to use your own SQL statement for given query.

Sample from doc

```
// Use raw SQL with an aggregate function  

String sql   
    = " select order_id, o.status, c.id, c.name, sum(d.order_qty*d.unit_price) as totalAmount"  
    + " from o_order o"   
    + " join o_customer c on c.id = o.kcustomer_id "  
    + " join o_order_detail d on d.order_id = o.id "  
    + " group by order_id, o.status ";  

RawSql rawSql =   
    RawSqlBuilder  
        // let ebean parse the SQL so that it can  
        // add expressions to the WHERE and HAVING   
        // clauses  
        .parse(sql)  
        // map resultSet columns to bean properties  
        .columnMapping("order_id",  "order.id")  
        .columnMapping("o.status",  "order.status")  
        .columnMapping("c.id",      "order.customer.id")  
        .columnMapping("c.name",    "order.customer.name")  
        .create();  


Query<OrderAggregate> query = Ebean.find(OrderAggregate.class);  
    query.setRawSql(rawSql)          
    // add expressions to the WHERE and HAVING clauses  
    .where().gt("order.id", 0)  
    .having().gt("totalAmount", 20);  

List<OrderAggregate> list = query.findList();
```

**Edit:** I just checked to feed my curiosity, also works (at least in Play framework):

```
Ebean.find(MyModel.class).where().like("concat(subject, ' ' , body)", "%foo%").findList();
```

Comment: While I am aware of this possibility, I would really like to stick with Ebean's built-in methods. I try to stay away from `RawSql` unless there's no other way around it

Comment: Wow, I didn't realize you could just inject your own raw SQL in this way; I thought it had to be done with a `RawSql` object. Nice find

Comment: Just note that there is also where().raw(...) - so alternatively you could have used that.